# Is it possible to use a custom field in where or having clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying the following SQL query:

```
  select (execution_end_timestamp - execution_queued_timestamp) as totalTime, execution_queued_timestamp from exec_queue
  where execution_name like '%Generate%'
  and execution_queued_timestamp > '2012-10-04 20:00:00.000'
  having totalTime < '1900-01-01 00:00:06.000'
```

I've tried using the totalTime in the where and having clause and in both cases it doesn't work. I also tried datediff hoping that might work, but it had identical results.

Is there a trick where you can use a computed field in a where or having clause? Googling around hasn't turned up anything except in cases where an aggregating function is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, alias is not allowed on `WHERE` clause, try,

```
select (execution_end_timestamp - execution_queued_timestamp) as totalTime, execution_queued_timestamp 
from exec_queue
where execution_name like '%Generate%' AND
      execution_queued_timestamp > '2012-10-04 20:00:00.000' AND
      (execution_end_timestamp - execution_queued_timestamp) < '1900-01-01 00:00:06.000'
```

Reason why `ALIAS` doesn't work on `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause,

- First the product of all tables in the `from clause` is formed.
- The `where clause` is then evaluated to eliminate rows that do not satisfy the search_condition.
- Next, the rows are grouped using the columns in the `group by clause`.
- Then, Groups that do not satisfy the search_condition in the `having claus`e are eliminated.
- Next, the expressions in the `select clause` target list are evaluated.
- If the `distinct keyword` in present in the select clause, duplicate rows are now eliminated.
- The `union` is taken after each sub-select is evaluated.
- Finally, the resulting rows are sorted according to the columns specified in the `order by clause`.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: I typically make the original query a derived table and then use my where clause on the alias as returned by the derived table. Is this considered inefficient?

Comment: @MrMoose It somewhat decreases the performance because you have added it on extra temporary table. It's up to you to choose over performance vs clarity :D

Comment: Thanks John. It'd be nice if I only had performance and clarity to choose between :)

Comment: @John - care to back this statement `It somewhat decreases the performance` up?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I mean it added extra work on the server. Why would you add it in a subquery if you can directly do it in where clause?

Comment: `I mean it added extra work on the server` AFAIK, it doesn't. You can check execution plans easily. `Why would you add it in a subquery if you can directly do it in where clause?` I hadn't commented on that. Are you deflecting?

Answer (score 3):

I used to have links to the SQL-92, 99 and 2003 ISO standards, but [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/) will do for now.

Basically, the sequence of query execution is

```
1. FROM/JOIN
2. WHERE/ON   -- exception for LEFT JOIN
3. GROUP BY (incl. CUBE, ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS)
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. DISTINCT
7. ORDER BY
```

So the aliases that you create for the SELECT columns are not visible to the WHERE and HAVING phases.  It's really just copy and paste of the expression, quite trivial.  The edge case could be when you are dealing with long, complex formulae, which could be better off sub-queried, e.g.

```
select totalTime,
       execution_queued_timestamp
from (
    select (execution_end_timestamp - execution_queued_timestamp) as totalTime,
           execution_queued_timestamp
    from exec_queue
    where execution_name like '%Generate%'
      and execution_queued_timestamp > '2012-10-04 20:00:00.000'
) x
where totalTime < '1900-01-01 00:00:06.000'
```

I'll give you a hint. SQL Server actually *knows* to take the WHERE filter into the inner query and apply it against the base table, so no loss of performance there!